# Unable to create triggers in GCP cloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create triggers in cloud MySQL and facing the below error.

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Tried to set the global variable also but I getting superuser missing privileges.

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

How to create the trigger in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either use the Google Cloud Console GUI or the CLI **gcloud** to set database flags.

**Google Cloud Console GUI:**

- Open the Cloud SQL instance and click Edit.
- Scroll down to the Flags section.
- To set a flag that has not been set on the instance before, click Add item,  - choose the flag from the drop-down menu, and set its value.
- Click Save to save your changes.
  Confirm your changes under Flags on the Overview page.

**Using the CLI:**

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] \
  --database-flags log_bin_trust_function_creators=on
```